# Is there any possible way to create a "block" command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been looking for a tutorial for a block command from YouTube to Google and I still can't find any.
For example: `!block @user`. The bot will not respond to the blocked user message. I been researching discord.js library but couldn't find any except [`User.block()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=block), but it's only available when using a user account.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. Your bot cannot use the block API, it can only be done from a regular user account.

Comment: Hmm do using a "blacklist" works or you have another way??

Answer (score 1):

You can make the command save the ID of the target in an array, then ignore the message if it comes from that user.

```
// At the top of your code:
var blockedUsers = [];

// Inside you command
if (command == 'block') {
  let user = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (user && !blockedUsers.includes(user.id)) blockedUsers.push(user.id);
}

// When you want to check if the user is blocked, at the top of your client.on('message') event listener
client.on('message', message => {
  if (blockedUsers.includes(message.author.id) || message.author.bot || /* all of your stuff that you want to ignore */) return;

  // The rest of your code...
});
```

Please note that the array will be reset every time you restart the bot, unless you store it in a json file or in a databse

Comment: Small note for the original poster: the list of blocked users will reset every time the bot is restarted. If you want to store the list of blocked users, look into saving them into a json file.

Comment: Yup, I've added it to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

All you simply have to do is:

```
let blacklist = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#e31212")
  .setDescription(
    "ERROR: You are blacklisted in the database by the owner from using this command."
  );
var blacklistarray =["", "", "", ""];// ID or ID(s) of user you wish to blacklist here
if (blacklistarray.includes(message.author.id))
  return message.channel.send(blacklist);
```

This will block the user you wish from a certain command. Make sure you put this at the top of the command you want to blacklist the user from.